# Caused by error in `pluck()`: while using pmap function in R purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I am using the `pmap` function to summarise my data in one column, and I am taking this weird error that I can not take it off. It's so odd, and its the first time I encounter it while using the function for a long time. And, of course, it comes just before a presentation.

```
 iris |> 
mutate(Species,data = pmap(across(-Species), list))
```

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `data = pmap(across(-Species), list)`.
Caused by error in `pluck()`:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

The weird think is that if I create a container where I use only `tidyverse` it works well. There might a package conflict but it was working a day ago

```r
library(tidyverse)  

iris |> 
mutate(Species,data = pmap(across(-Species), list)) |> 
  head()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species               data
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't get an error when doing `iris |> 
  mutate(Species, data = pmap(across(-Species), list))`. Can you share your sessionInfo?

Comment: Same for me when I use only tidyverse, but if i use any other package I get this odd error that drives me nuts

Comment: There should be a way to create the same list with summarise and keep the columns. I am so blind to wrath now that I can not think. I ll create another post